# Flutter Background Timer

Tags: android, ios, flutter, background

I am making a uber like app, where the driver needs to update their coordinates to the database every 1 minute. I have a timer that is running every minute that fetches the user coordinates and update the db. However, when I put the app in the background (driver looking at google maps), the timer duration changes (Starts from 1 minutes, it become 2 - 3 - longer). I have it allowed to run from the background and fetch location from the background, as well as ignore battery optimization.

I tried background locator 2 (distance filter doesn't work).
background fetch looks like it runs every 15 minutes.

I need a solution that can run every minute to fetch the user location and update the database for both android and ios, and customer to continuously listen to the driver location from the background and update to send alerts (Driver is arriving in 3 minutes).

FYI, I am currently using Microsoft/signalr for the customer app to listen to the driver location.

```
    locationTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: STATUSUPDATE), (Timer t) async {
      await fetchCurrentLocation();
    });
```

Are there any solution to keep android and ios app running normally from the background?

Comment: what about using `workmanager` package https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: I see that IOS only supprots oneOfTask (running once) and Android minimun interval is 15minutes. I need to update it every minute for both ios and android.

Comment: On iOS you can't use a timer driven approach. If you have always and background location then you will receive location updates on a regular basis (about once per second if you are using gps). In the update callback delegate you can check the time since you last updated the server and if it is more than a minutes send a location update to your server.

Comment: By using the diff way, I wonder how to make precise interval, like 30s to make a request to server?  Current location update interval seems to be unstable.